# how to make .equ directive global so that it can be used in other files?

Tags: assembly, arm64, gnu-assembler

As a toy project I'm building some project using nothing but ARM64. I have some file called pairs.s that contains an implementation for some kind of struct/class, I have an .equ directive called pairs_size that defines the size of that class, and I want to used that class in another .s file so where the pairs class is used inside another class so I need to calculate the size of that class in compile time by adding the two classes size:

here is pairs.s:

```
.global     pairs_ctor
.global     pairs_ctor_dynamic

.equ        constant_power_pair_size,               16
.equ        constant_power_pair_power_offset,       0
.equ        constant_power_pair_constant_offset,    8

that is the .equ I would like to use in another file
**.equ        pairs_size,                         40**
.equ        pairs_pairs_offset,                 0
.equ        pairs_count_offset,                 8
.equ        pairs_capacity_offset,              16
.equ        pairs_single_power_offset,          24
.equ        pairs_single_constant_offset,       32

//        pairs*  pairs_ctor_dynamic();
pairs_ctor_dynamic:
    stp     x29, x30, [sp, -16]!
    stp     d0, d1, [sp, -16]!
    mov     x0, pairs_size
    bl      malloc
    ldp     d0, d1, [sp], 16
    ldp     x29, x30, [sp], 16
//        void    pairs_ctor(_ x0 : pairs*, _ d0 : power, _ d1 : constant);
pairs_ctor:
    add     x1, x0, pairs_single_power_offset
    str     x1, [x0, pairs_pairs_offset]
    mov     x1, 1
    stp     x1, x1, [x0, pairs_count_offset] // count = capacity = 1
    str     d0, [x0, pairs_single_power_offset]
    str     d1, [x0, pairs_single_constant_offset]
    ret
```

the other file is for example ASTX.s:

```
ASTX_vtable:
    .quad ASTX_evaluate
    .quad ASTX_derivative
    .quad ASTX_toString

// unfortunately that line doesn't compile! 
**.equ    ASTX_size,  16+pairs_size**
```

Comment: Put them in a shared include file.

Comment: Either what @Michael says, or make the symbols global with a `.global` directive.

Comment: @fuz .global doesn't seem to work on .equ directives.

Comment: @MkInitCpIO It does work for me.  Can you give a specific example of what you tried?

Comment: @fuz I've tried it with the example above, adding .global pairs_size and trying using it in ASTX.s has not worked for me.

Comment: @MkInitCpIO “has not worked for me” is not an error description.  Anyway, the problem is that arithmetic you perform on external symbols is limited.  And you cannot define symbols in terms of arithmetic on external symbols.

Comment: @fuz so what is the solution then? will usage of complex structures in handmade assembly always be messy and complicated?

Comment: @MkInitCpIO As Michael said, use include directives and put the symbols into common files.  I recommend doing this using the C preprocessor.  If you suffix your files with `.S`, they will be processed through the C preprocessor before assembly.

Comment: .global worked for me :)